# Get path from a file that trigger an app

Tags: blackberry, filesystems, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde, delete-file

I´m downloading a file to a SD card in the BlackBerry, and when I open that file, my application run. So when my application run, I need to delete that file.

The problem is that I dont know where it is(the file) from my app, because the user could download that file anywhere.
Is there something in the BB OS that let me know the path of that file? With this I can give to my app a parameter or something...

Well, thats it.

Answer (score 0):

If you register with invocation registry so that your app is invoked whenever file needs to be opened, you will get full URL in Invocation object. This URL is sufficient to delete the file via FileConnector.

See [this BlackBerry example](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11942/Create_BB_app_plays_media_from_a_user_734821_11.jsp) to properly register your app. Also, in step 6 note invoc.getURL() - this is what you need to use.